# $_POST not working properly from JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, input

I've created the button:

```
<input type = "text" name="consulta" size = "12" value = "565656" id = "consulta" />
<input type="button" value = "Pesquisar" onclick="jawa()" />
```

and the jawa() function is:

```
        function jawa(){
            var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById('pesquisa');

                            //just for test if JS takes values....
                            resultado = consulta.value;
            escolha = cbox.value;

            fieldNameElement.innerHTML = "<?echoo();?>";            
        }
```

and the echoo() in php...

```
                   <? 
                       function echoo(){

             if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) { 
                $con = $_POST['consulta'];
            }else{
            $con = "not working";
            }

            $conexao =mysql_pconnect("localhost:3306","xxx","xxx");
            mysql_select_db("...",$conexao);

            $str_chamado = "Select * 
                    From
                        `...`.`...` 
                    Where
                        `NU_TELEFONE`='$con'";

                         ...   ?>
```

it says that "Undefined index: consulta" I can't get the text from the input, what can it be?

Comment: It will not work. Echo function will be called when rendering the page. what you need is an ajax request. IMHO http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ is the easiest way.

Comment: You will need to make a Ajax Call from your javascript to your PHP page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function from Javascript, because PHP it's interpreted before the page shows and cannot interact with it afterwards.

You can achieve that with Ajax or sending the form and process the values with PHP and the output whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry the language, but this is a hell of a mess! When you post the form, you should have your PHP seperat from your javascript above the html-start-tag in your document (very beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Besides you didn't also define "consulta" this is why you are getting that Undefined Index error.